# foreign key constraint not working through program.but working with terminal

Tags: iphone, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am having foreign key constraint in my table but when i am inserting data using terminal it is working fine but when i doing it in xcode project it is not working
what may be the problem.
how can i enable pragma foreign_keys = ON,through program.
I am using below code for insertion but i think foreign key is not enabled.
just tell me how can i enable foreign keys through program.

```
+(BOOL)insertEmployee:(int)din :(NSString*)name{

NSArray *arrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *strDestPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/samplepillbox1.sqlite",[arrDocPath objectAtIndex:0]];

sqlite3 *dbEmployee;
if(sqlite3_open([strDestPath UTF8String], &dbEmployee)==SQLITE_OK)
{

    //NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into maintable_master(din,brand_name) values(%d,'%@')",din,name];
    //NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into doctor_master(din,firstname) values(%d,'%@')",din,name];
    NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into schedule_master(din,start_date) values(%d,'%@')",din,name];
    void *v;
    char *errmsg;
    if(sqlite3_exec(dbEmployee, [insertQuery UTF8String], 0, v, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"inserted successfully");
        return YES;
    }
}
return NO;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set the pragma just as you would run a more standard SQL statement. Typically, you set the pragma immediately after opening the database connection.

So your code should look something along this:

```
// 1. open the connection
...

// 2. set the pragma
if (sqlite3_exec(dbEmployee, @"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", 0, v, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to set the foreign_key pragma");
    return -1;
}
```